# need to bring back win 7

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, grub

I like making music and playing games and occasionally do some Photoshop. I had a windows 8 computer but my mouse pointer always got stuck, so to try out something new I installed Ubuntu. here is how I installed it:

1. Went to advanced statup options
2. clicked on "use a device" after plugging in my bootable USB with Ubuntu
3. replaced my windows 8 and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I hope I did it correctly though.

So after a few months I could've really find out a good Audio Production (not LMMS, because I use Stagelight) software nor something that could be familiar to the UI of Photoshop.

So I decided to bring back Windows, but because of the bad experience of 8 I thought about bringing back win 7

So I used an app named WinUSB to make my bootable USB drive after formatting it to NTFS in GParted

But when I go to my grub menu, my USB doesn't show up and my PC being a UEFI device. I don't know how to get to the bios of my device.

Can somebody tell how to install Windows 7 completely and deleting Ubuntu or at least give me a link to a tutorial.

I have a netbook: it is an Acer Aspire One 725.
I'm fine with using commands in terminal and another thing that my laptop doesn't have a CD drive or reader, I can't put a CD inside

Comment: Can you use Win7 DVD?

Answer (score 0):

Reformat the USB drive to FAT32, mark the partition active, then move the install files there.

UEFI systems aren't able to boot off NTFS volumes, even if they're marked as active and have all needed files.